# How do I unmap a key binding only in buffers of a filetype?

Tags: vim

I have a mapping `;;` to move to the end of line and insert a colon (useful in c-like languages). And in my `scheme.vim` file I have:

```
iunmap ;;
```

Problem with this is:

1. It will try to run this command every time I open a scheme file, at which point it's already unmapped, so I will get a warning.
2. It will unmap this key globally, so if I open a non-scheme file in the same session, it will not remember this binding.

At the very least I would like to solve #1, and have it only attempt to unmap if the binding is active so that I don't get an error.

Comment: Did you try `iunmap <buffer> ;;`?

Comment: what do you mean? that will thrown an error since I'm not mapping anything to a `<buffer>` key.

Comment: `<buffer>` is not a key, it's an argument for the `:map` family of commands that restricts the mapping to the current buffer. That argument is used in ftplugins to prevent custom filetype-specific mappings to leak into other filetypes. You can use that command if you want to disable a mapping created by an ftplugin and that ftplugin is competently written. That command unmaps the buffer-local mapping `;;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably be best to make your `;;` mapping a buffer local mapping based on the `'filetype'`.

```
autocmd FileType c,javascript inoremap <buffer> ;; <esc>m'A;<esc>``a
```

You can add as many filetypes as you need to this mapping. Just separate filetypes with commas.

For more help see:

```
:h :au
:h :map-local
:h 'filetype'
:h FileType
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following map to achieve:

```
imap <buffer> ;; ;;
```

Comment: I found this answer more practical than the accepted answer for my situation.  I guess it depends on the situation though.